# How to can i change textview size and position in Android ListView on runtime

Tags: android, mono

I have a ListView with 3 textview on the same line, inflated from a axml file, each textview has a value, like a table.
I need to change size and position (x axis only) of these textview at runtime.
I think I've tried EVERYTHING, and nothing works.

This is my code:

```
    public override Android.Views.View GetView (int position, Android.Views.View convertView, 
                                           Android.Views.ViewGroup parent)
{           
    var view = convertView;
    if (convertView == null || !(convertView is LinearLayout))            
        view = CurrAct.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.XXX, parent, false);

    if (position == _CurrPos)            
        SelectRow(view);
    else            
        view.SetBackgroundColor(CurrAct.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.solidwhite)); 

    TextView[] LocArrTxt = new TextView[3];
    LocArrTxt[0] = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.TextView0);
    LocArrTxt[1] = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.TextView1);
    LocArrTxt[2] = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.TextView2);

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        LocArrTxt[i].Text = NewValue; 
        LocArrTxt[i].Layout(NewLeft, OriginalTop, NewRight, OriginalBottom);
        LocArrTxt[i].SetWidth(NewRight-NewLeft);           
    }                 

    return view;
}
```

and this is the file axml: a horizontal linearlayout with 3 textview.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/LinLay"
    android:background="#ffffffff">
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:id="@+id/TextView0"
        style="@style/BlackLabel"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        style="@style/BlackLabel"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        style="@style/BlackLabel"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea?
I've lost 2 days without a solution.

Comment: What is it you are overriding ???

Comment: public override Android.Views.View GetView (int position, Android.Views.View convertView,Android.Views.ViewGroup parent). Looks completely wrong.

Comment: I'm overriding the Adapter.GetView method.
Why wrong? It works perfectly except for the resize of the 3 textview.

Comment: If you're going to change the `TextView`'s dimension that assign that dimension in the `getView` method, also don't use the weight.

Comment: Using weight was my last attempt, but nothing changes using weight or not: textview always mantain same size and position.

Comment: *I need to change size and position (x axis only) of these textview at runtime* - in which way are you trying to change their position? I don't know mono but if the `Layout((NewLeft, OriginalTop, NewRight, OriginalBottom);)` represent the method from the `ViewGroup` class which is responsible for placing the children in the parent you're not using it right. Also you didn't mention in your code **how** you try to change the dimension in position for those ListView rows items.